# UiViewController rotation question

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, rotation, landscape, portrait

I have main menu in my app supporting only landscape mode.
I implement landscape restriction by setting up `UIRootViewController::shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:...`
And I have another scene with portrait mode support.
So the problem appears when I pass from another scene to main menu in portrait mode: the app doesn't rotate to landscape automatically, and I can't find a code method to manually rotate it.

Is there a solution? Would be thankful.

Edit: Excuse me, I forgot to add details. RootViewController is common for menu and another scene. And what is more - these scenes are in one common view (my app uses OpenGL)
So before I enter menu from portrait scene I set `UIRootViewController::shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` to return YES for landscape only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your other scene with portrait support is controlled by another UIViewController, then you can use that view controller's -shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: to define its behavior. In many cases, this alone should be enough. Of course, if you need to do some fancy rotations for some view controller but not for others, then things get a bit trickier.

Comment: I stopped on this solution: kill my existing RootViewController and create new one with another rotation restrictions. Seems the view controller is not designed to change autorotation settings in runtime.

Comment: Could you keep the landscape-only root view controller and push another view controller onto navigation controller stack to show the other scene (that supports both/all orientations)?

Comment: Both scenes (main menu and another scene) are in one common view (OpenGL). I didn`t try but I think that it is bad idea to control one view by two controllers. If you have experience in this case please share it. It would be interesting.

Comment: I didn't realize that this was the case. My apps don't make a lot of use of OpenGL - just one view within a larger Core Graphics view. However, I would suggest considering the following: addObserver for UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification and have -shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: always return YES. Then manage the rotation yourself, using transforms. You will want to rotate view to keep it appearing in landscape. This is what I would try, now that I better understand the constraints. But it is not something that I have done.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do this, except [UIDevice setOrientation:], which is not open to developers, and leads to application rejection by Apple.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a rotation to your layer which will create the exact same effect.

```
myview.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI/2, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
```